# Attempting to disable a button when a Short? field reaches the value 5

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to disable a button when a UNIT_NUMBER Short? field reaches the value 5. not sure how to do this.

I have a form that auto-increments the UNIT_NUMBER field based on my Sub New. It increments fine

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Record As Feature, ByVal previousRecord As Till_NonTillStation, ByVal SurficialType As enumTillTypes)
    MyBase.New(Record, Constants.COL_TILL_CREATED_BY, Constants.COL_TILL_CREATION_DATE, Constants.COL_TILL_EDITED_BY, Constants.COL_TILL_EDIT_DATE, DirectCast(previousRecord.Geometry, Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint))

    Try
        _incrementStationCount = False
        _surficialObsType = SurficialType

        'Values carried over on both forms
        Me.SITE_ID = previousRecord.SITE_ID
        Me.EXPOSURE_TYPE = previousRecord.EXPOSURE_TYPE
        Me.EXPOSURE_HEIGHT = previousRecord.EXPOSURE_HEIGHT

        If previousRecord.UNIT_NUMBER Is Nothing Then
            Me.UNIT_NUMBER = 1S
        Else

            Me.UNIT_NUMBER = previousRecord.UNIT_NUMBER + 1S

        End If

            If Me.OBSERVATION_TYPE = enumTillTypes.Non_Till Then
            'FIRST_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0
            SECOND_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0
            THIRD_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0
            FOURTH_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0

        End If

        If Me.OBSERVATION_TYPE = enumTillTypes.Till Then
            FIRST_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0
            SECOND_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0
            THIRD_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0
            FOURTH_LITHOFACIES_INTERVAL = 0

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Constants.WriteToErrorLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType.Name,
                             System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name,
                             ex)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Button Control:

Comment: You want to disable a button, why do you put all the irrelevant code around your question. And post the minimum required to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if UNIT_NUMBER = 5 then button1.enable = false
```